# How to set default value on reactive form after the form has been initialized?

Tags: angular, typescript, forms, reactive

I have a master component and child components. Each child component is supposed to be part of a form.

- Master Component (form)

  - Tab 1 (formGroup1)
  - Tab 2 (formGroup2)
  - Tab 3 (formGroup3)

I created the form inside Master Component and passed a formGroup to each child component as a parameter. In each child component I request the data from an API and populate the form group.

But I want the user to be able to reset the form and retrieve the default values from inside each child.

So how do I set the default value of the formGroup after it has been initialized?

Comment: How are you passing the FormGroups from the master component to the child components? Are you using @Input() annotations?

Comment: @harleybl Yes, I am.